# Change obj.innerHTML in Javascript? Game of Life

Tags: javascript

I have implemented the Game of Life in Javascript.  I am thinking about making a combobox which a listof colors to choose from.  From there I want to render the obj.innerHTML img source of my grid cells in the game.  What would be the best way to go about this?

Here is my code so far for the game:

```
    <br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="100%" height="80%"></canvas>

    <button onClick="generateLevel()">Create New Board</button>
    <button onClick="step()">Step</button>
    <button onClick="multiStep()">Multistep</button>    

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var level;
    var lastLevelDrawn;
    var lvlWidth = 0;
    var lvlHeight = 0;

    function step()
    {

        var tempLevel = new Array(lvlHeight);
        for (var y = 0; y < lvlHeight; y++)
        {
            tempLevel[y] = new Array(lvlWidth);
            for (var x = 0; x < lvlWidth; x++)
            {
                var liveNeighborCount = 0;
                var status = level[y][x];
                for (var k = y-1; k < y+2; k++)
                {
                    for (var j = x-1; j < x+2; j++)
                    {
                        if (k == y && j == x)
                        {

                        }
                        else if (k >= 0 && k < lvlHeight && j >= 0 && j < lvlWidth)
                        {
                            if (level[k][j] == "1")
                            {
                                liveNeighborCount++;
                            }
                        }   
                    }
                }

                if (level[y][x] == "1")
                {
                    if (liveNeighborCount != 2 && liveNeighborCount != 3)
                    {
                        status = "0";
                    }

                }
                if (level[y][x] == "0")
                {
                    if (liveNeighborCount == 3)
                    {
                        status = "1";

                    }

                }
                tempLevel[y][x] = status;                   
            }
        }
        level = tempLevel;
        render();
    }       

    function multiStep()
    {
                    var steps = prompt("How many steps do you want to step?", "10");
        for (var x = 0; x < steps; x++)
            step();
    }   

    function generateLevel()
    {

        var width = prompt("How many cells wide?", "10");
        var height = prompt("How many cells high?", "10");
        lvlWidth = width;
        lvlHeight = height;
        var output = "";
        if (width != null && height != null)
        {
            level = new Array(lvlHeight);
            lastLevelDrawn = new Array(lvlHeight);
            for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                level[y] = new Array(lvlWidth);
                lastLevelDrawn[y] = new Array(lvlWidth);
                for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    level[y][x] = Math.floor((Math.random()*2));
                    lastLevelDrawn[y][x] = -1;
                    output += " " + level[y][x];
                }
                output += "<br>";
            }
        }

        //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=output;
        setupRender();
    }

    function changeTile(tile)
    {
        var x = tile % lvlWidth;
        var y = parseInt(tile/lvlWidth);
        //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x + ":" + y;
        if (level[y][x] == "1")
            level[y][x] = "0";
        else
            level[y][x] = "1";

        render();           
    }

    function render()
    {
        var widPer = ((1/lvlWidth)*90);
        var heiPer = ((1/lvlHeight)*70);
        for (var y = 0; y < lvlHeight; y++)
        {
            for (var z = 0; z < lvlWidth; z++)
            {
                var send = y*lvlWidth + z;
                if (lastLevelDrawn[y][z] != level[y][z])
                {
                    lastLevelDrawn[y][z] = level[y][z];
                    var obj = document.getElementById(send);
                    if (level[y][z] == "1")
                        obj.innerHTML = "<img src='white.jpg' width='" + widPer + "%' height='" + heiPer + "%' onclick='changeTile(" + send + ")'/>";
                    else 
                        obj.innerHTML = "<img src='black.jpg' width='" + widPer + "%' height='" + heiPer + "%' onclick='changeTile(" + send + ")'/>";
                }
            }
        }
    }


    function setupRender()
    {   
        var x = "";
        var widPer = ((1/lvlWidth)*90);
        var heiPer = ((1/lvlHeight)*70);
        //x += "<table border='1' col width='((1/lvlWidth)*100)%' col height='((1/lvlHeight)*80)%'>";
        for (var y = 0; y < lvlHeight; y++)
        {
            //x += "<tr>";
            for (var z = 0; z < lvlWidth; z++)
            {
                lastLevelDrawn[y][z] = level[y][z];
                //x += level[y][z];
                var send = y*lvlWidth + z;
                x += "<n id='" + send + "'>";
                if (level[y][z] == "1")
                    x += "<img src='white.jpg' width='" + widPer + "%' height='" + heiPer + "%' onclick='changeTile(" + send + ")'/>";
                else 
                    x += "<img src='black.jpg' width='" + widPer + "%' height='" + heiPer + "%' onclick='changeTile(" + send + ")'/>";
                x += "</n>";

            }
            x += "<br>";
            //x += "</tr>";
        }
        //x += "</table>";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
    }       

    </script>
```